# Xonix-игра Проблемы с оптимизацией на Corona SDk

Tags: инспекция-кода, lua, coronasdk

Я делаю игру Xonix на Corona SDK. В качестве игрового поля я решил использовать сетку квадратов. Ширина 44, Высота 71. В результате я получил ряд, состоящий из 3124 (44 * 71) квадратов, по которым движется игрок. Но у меня проблемы с оптимизацией. Движок не справляется с таким количеством квадратов на экране одновременно. Из-за этого FPS на смартфоне не больше 12. Помогите найти лучшее решение. Все что касается полигонов и мешей, я не силен в геометрии.

Уменьшение количества квадратов - плохая идея. Тогда внешний вид теряется, и поле захватывается слишком большими кусками.

Заранее спасибо!

```
    -- Получить все свободные ячейки
    -- суши
    M.get_free = function(_i,_j,_start)
        local _par = pairs
        local _fill = M.filling_arr
        local _arr = M.arr_pole
        local _index = {
            {-1,-1}, {0,-1}, {1,-1},
            {-1, 0},         {1, 0},
            {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1},
        }

        -- помечаем как проверенный
        _arr[_i][_j].is_check = true
        _fill[#_fill+1] = {_i,_j}

        for k,v in _par(_index) do
            local i = _i+v[1]
            local j = _j+v[2]

            if i>1 and i<M.delta_height
                and j>1 and j<M.delta_width then

                if not _arr[i][j].is_check then

                    if _arr[i][j].type==2 then
                        M.get_free(i,j)
                    end
                end

            end
        end

        if _start then
            return _fill
        end
    end

    -- Закрашиваем область
    M.filling = function()
        -- инициализация
        local par = pairs
        local tb_rem = table.remove

        local arr = M.arr_pole
        M.island_arr = {}

        -- сбросить индикатор проверки
        for i,ii in par(arr) do
            for j,jj in par(ii) do
                if jj.type==2 then
                    jj.is_check = false
                end
            end
        end

        -- делим сушу на острова
        for i,ii in par(arr) do
            for j,jj in par(ii) do
                if jj.type==2 and not jj.is_check then
                    M.filling_arr = {}
                    M.island_arr[#M.island_arr+1] = M.get_free(i,j,true)
                end
            end
        end

        -- находим больший остров и удаляем его
        local sel_max = {dir = '', count = 1}
        for k,v in par(M.island_arr) do
            if #v>=sel_max.count then
                sel_max.dir = k
                sel_max.count = #v
            end
        end
        if #M.island_arr>0 then
            tb_rem(M.island_arr,sel_max.dir)
        end

        -- закрашиваем
        for k,v in par(M.island_arr) do
            for kk,vv in par(v) do
                local obj = arr[vv[1]][vv[2]]
                obj.type = 0

                obj[1].isVisible = false
            end
        end

        -- превращаем края в воду
        for k,v in par(M.bread_crumbs) do
            local arr = arr[v.arr_y][v.arr_x]
            arr.type = 0

            arr[1].isVisible = false
        end

        -- чистка истории
        M.clear_history()
    end
```

```
    -- Создание игрового поля
    M.create_pole = function()
        -- инициализация
        local image = display.newImage
        local rect = display.newRect
        local rrect = display.newRoundedRect
        local floor = math.floor

        M.GR_ZONE = display.newGroup()
        M.POLE = {}

        -- картинка
        M.POLE.bg = rrect(0,0,150,150,5)
        M.POLE.bg.width = M.width_pole
        M.POLE.bg.height = M.height_pole
        M.POLE.bg.x = _W/2
        M.POLE.bg.y = _H/2
        M.POLE.bg.xScale = _H*.00395
        M.POLE.bg.yScale = _H*.00395
        M.POLE.bg:setFillColor(API.hexToCmyk(M.color.land))
        M.GR:insert(M.POLE.bg)

        M.POLE.img = image(IMAGES..'picture/test.jpg')
        M.POLE.img.width = M.width_pole-M.size_xonix
        M.POLE.img.height = M.height_pole-M.size_xonix
        M.POLE.img.x = _W/2
        M.POLE.img.y = _H/2
        M.POLE.img.xScale = _H*.00395
        M.POLE.img.yScale = _H*.00395
        M.POLE.img.strokeWidth = 1.3
        M.POLE.img:setStrokeColor(API.hexToCmyk(M.color.img))
        M.GR:insert(M.POLE.img)

        -- управленеи игроком
        M.POLE.bg:addEventListener( 'touch', M.swipe )
        M.POLE.bg:addEventListener( 'tap', function(e)
            M.POLE.player.state = 0
        end )

        -- массив поля
        M.arr_pole = {} -- сегменты поля
        local jj = 0
        for i=1,M.delta_height do -- 71 
            M.arr_pole[i] = {}
            M.GUI.border[i] = {}
            for k=1,M.delta_width do - 44
                jj = jj+1
                M.arr_pole[i][k] = {nm = jj}
                M.GUI.border[i][k] = {}

                -- координаты
                local xx = k*M.size_xonix
                local yy = i*M.size_xonix

                local _x = floor(xx-M.size_xonix/2)
                local _y = floor(yy-M.size_xonix/2)

                M.arr_pole[i][k][1] = image(IMAGES..'pole/land.jpg')
                M.arr_pole[i][k][1] .x = _x
                M.arr_pole[i][k][1] .y = _y
                M.GR_ZONE:insert(M.arr_pole[i][k][1])

                -- вода по краям
                -- остальное суша
                if (i==1 or i==M.delta_height)
                    or (k==1 or k==M.delta_width) then
                    M.arr_pole[i][k].type = 0
                else
                    M.arr_pole[i][k].type = 2
                    M.arr_pole[i][k][1].isVisible = true
                end

            end
        end

        -- корректор координат
        M.GR_ZONE.width = M.POLE.bg.width*M.POLE.bg.xScale
        M.GR_ZONE.height = M.POLE.bg.height*M.POLE.bg.yScale
        M.GR_ZONE.x = M.POLE.bg.x-M.POLE.bg.width*M.POLE.bg.xScale/2
        M.GR_ZONE.y = M.POLE.bg.y-M.POLE.bg.height*M.POLE.bg.yScale/2

        -- игрок

        local _x = M.arr_pole[1][1][1].x
        local _y = M.arr_pole[1][1][1].y

        M.POLE.player = image(IMAGES..'ui/player.png')
        M.POLE.player.x = _x
        M.POLE.player.y = _y
        M.POLE.player.width = M.size_xonix*1.5
        M.POLE.player.height = M.size_xonix*1.5
        M.POLE.player.state = 0
        M.GR_ZONE:insert(M.POLE.player)

        -- поднимаем игрока
        M.POLE.player:toFront()
    end
```